# Unable to install boto3

Tags: python, virtualenv, boto3

I have trouble installing boto3 inside a virtual environment.

I have done what the document says. First I activated virtual environment. then I did a:

```
Sudo pip install boto3
```

Now I enter python

```
>> import boto3
ImportError: No module named boto3
```

But if I import boto, it works

```
>> import boto
>> boto.Version
'2.38.0'
```

Why does it install boto 2.38 when I installed boto3.
I tried closing the terminal and re-opened it.
Should I restart the Ubuntu machine?

Comment: Are you using python2.7?

Comment: Updating pip fix my problem `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` :)

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Don't use `sudo` in a virtual environment because it ignores the environment's variables and therefore `sudo pip` refers to your **global** pip installation.

So with your environment activated, rerun `pip install boto3` but without sudo.

Comment: Awesome, timely and perfect. Thank you very much. I will accept this as answer in 7 minutes.

Comment: fwiw using `sudo` on any install process is going to give you a headache. I recommend doing any installs without `sudo`

Comment: This worked for me. It doesn't work if you are trying to install it only on your virtual environment

Answer (score 104):

There is another possible scenario that might get some people as well (if you have python and python3 on your system):

```
pip3 install boto3
```

Note the use of `pip3` indicates the use of Python 3's pip installation vs just `pip` which indicates the use of Python 2's.

Comment: Thanks, worked for me. I was having both 2.7 and 3.4 versions.

Comment: This is working great on Python2.7 and Python3.6 both.

Answer (score 53):

try this way:

```
python -m pip install --user boto3
```

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me. Without virtual envs, without changing anything in my setup.

Comment: It was also the only solution for me on Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS with Python 3.5.2 + Python 2.7.12

Comment: for macOS [~Oct2020] using python3 instead of python for this answer worked for me.

Answer (score 22):

I had a similar problem, but the accepted answer did not resolve it - I was not using a virtual environment. This is what I had to do:

```
sudo python -m pip install boto3
```

I do not know why this behaved differently from `sudo pip install boto3`.

Answer (score 15):

I have faced the same issue and also not using virtual environment. easy_install is working for me.

```
easy_install boto3
```

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and my python version is 2.7

Comment: "sudo easy_install boto3" worked for me on Ubuntu 16

Comment: this worked for me. because pip would install boto3 only for python3.

Answer (score 14):

**For Python 3**

```
python3 -m pip install --user boto3
```

Source: https://github.com/boto/boto/issues/3194#issuecomment-668420011

Answer (score 3):

Activate virtual environment and run following command:

```sh
pip install boto3
```

for Windows user

Answer (score 1):

Do not run as sudo, just type:

`pip3 install boto3==1.7.40 --user`

Enjoy

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. This will work for VSCode:

1. Install the Python extension for VSCode
2. Create new folder and add a python script in it
3. Install venv and activate inside VSCode Console in your project:

   python3 -m venv venv
   source ./venv/bin/activate
   (venv) My-MacBook-Air:python-scripts user$

Notice venv is activated: (venv)

4. Install boto3 inside the activated venv environment:

   pip3 install boto3
5. Check your venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages folder to confirm boto3 is in there.

6. Press CMD + Shift + P and set the python interpret to ./venv/bin/python. Note you may also need to press "CMD ,", enter "python.pythonPath" and set the Python Path appropriately.

Then it will work for sure!

Answer (score 0):

I have the similar issue. In my system Anaconda distribution is installed. While running my python program in the Juypyter notebook, it was showing

`no module named 'boto3'`

While checking in command prompt

```
>pip install boto3
```

Requirement already satisfied.

Inorder to resolve the same for Juypyter notebook, open "Anaconda Prompt" and

`install Boto3` using

```
pip install boto3
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I was facing the same issue on windows and I resolved by following the below steps.

1. `>>> exit()` - exist python

   [image]
2. `pip3 install boto3` - execute this command

   [image]

Answer (score 0):

In VScode terminal, Sudo is not required.
**pip install boto3** will install boto3

Answer (score -1):

Though this is an old post, I am posting how I resolved in case it helps others. Since I used sudo to do the install of the boto3 library the permissions on the boto3 directory was set to 700. Either change the permissions to be readable by others or run the python command as sudo.

Answer (score -1):

In Pycharm

```
Press Ctr + Alt + s
 On left, Project <your project here> > Project Interpreter
  On right, click on +
  At the top, search for boto3
  At the bottom, click on Install Package
```

Comment: not all developers use Pycharm, so a better solution is indicate general instructions like pip install boto3 in the virtual enviroment.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue and it turned out that boto3 wasn't installed in the same directory as my python interpreter. It's worth it to check that if all the solutions above don't work for you.

Comment: Please be sure to either convert this post into a comment or to turn it into a qualified answer (see [answer] for guidance)

Answer (score -3):

Try this it works
sudo apt install python-pip
pip install boto3

Comment: See Leistungsabfall's answer.