# ImportError: No module named boto3

Tags: raspberry-pi2, boto3

Installed the boto3 and upgraded it to the latest release. I tried the easy install pip for installation. I have multiple versions of python installed so I even tried installing in virtualenv venv. But I get the same error: "No module named boto3".

```
pip install boto3

python
Python 2.7.11 (default, Mar 10 2016, 14:12:44)
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import boto3
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named boto3
>>>
```

I tried with / without sudo:

```
sudo pip install boto3
```

I`m trying to install AWS SDK on Raspberry Pi.

```
pip freeze
```

shows "boto3==1.3.0" installed.

```
sudo pip install boto3

Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): boto3 in    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): botocore>=1.4.1, <1.5.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from boto3)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): jmespath>=0.7.1,<1.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from boto3)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): futures>=2.2.0,<4.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from boto3)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): python-dateutil>=2.1,<3.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from botocore>=1.4.1,<1.5.0->boto3)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): docutils>=0.10 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from botocore>=1.4.1,<1.5.0->boto3)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six>=1.5 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.1,<3.0.0->botocore>=1.4.1,<1.5.0->boto3)
Cleaning up...
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

sudo pip install boto3 installs it to your global pip. Explained here: [Unable to install boto3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33388555/unable-to-install-boto3)

You can activate your venv, install boto3 without sudo and start python:

```
$ source path/to/your/ENV/bin/activate
$ pip install boto3
$ python
```

Or if you prefer to use your global installation do:

```
$ deactivate
$ pip install boto3
$ python
```

Check out the virtualenv user guide: https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide.html

Also virtualenvwrapper makes it really easy to manage:
https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html

Comment: If this isn't working for you, refer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20952797/pip-installing-in-global-site-packages-instead-of-virtualenv

Answer (score 3):

Globally for my mac, this worked

```
sudo pip install --ignore-installed six boto3
```

Comment: @BaseDesire 'six' happens to be a dependency for the boto3 package
More: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/3165

Answer (score 1):

Try to activate your virtual environment

> source bin/activate

Then try connecting installing boto3

> pip install boto3

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue and also not using virtual environment. easy_install is working for me. I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and my python version is 2.7

```
easy_install boto3
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes botocore is also needed, so install boto3 and botocore.