# Import boto3 error in python

Tags: python, boto3

I installed `boto3` using `pip2.7 install boto3`. Now when I do `python2.7 script.py` which has `import boto3`, I get `ImportError: No module named boto3`. When I again do `pip2.7 install boto3` I get `Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): boto3 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`.

Why is this error coming and how can I resolve it?

**NOTE:** I did `pip2.7 install boto3` based on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33388555/unable-to-install-boto3)

Comment: Please try to install it under Virtualenv, which is standardise.  Due to different OS setup,  pip might install package into folder that not inside correct PYTHONPATH.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue and also not using virtual environment. easy_install is working for me. I am using ubuntu 16.04 and python version 2.7

```
easy_install boto3
```