# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'boto3' using Anaconda

Tags: python, boto3, conda

I have installed boto3 module using Windows 10 CMD and restarted my kernel. However, the kernel cannot find the module and shows the error

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'boto3' when tested using Anaconda

I have used pip3 because I am using Python 3

Here are my installation steps

```
pip3 install boto3

pip3 show boto3
```

> shows the details of the installed boto3 package

What could be the problem?

Comment: And what does the code look like ? did you import it ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to install boto3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33388555/unable-to-install-boto3)

Comment: You should also be sure that pip3 is installing modules to the correct location. For example I had a similar issue when I had a virtual environment and after performing an incorrect pip upgrade modules were installed in the wrong location.

Comment: _I have used pip3 because I am using Python 3_ Are you not using Conda?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using windows and you have Anaconda installed, it gets simple
Open

> Anaconda Powershell Prompt (Anaconda3)

and run as an administrator. This will give you the privilege to install the package to the Environment
Then run

```
conda install -c anaconda boto3
```

It should work

Answer (score 5):

Try installing using this command

```
python -m pip install --user boto3
```

Comment: Conda generally encourages users to prefer installing through Conda rather than Pip when the package is available through both. Further, the `--user` flag should never be used in a virtual environment because it will install outside the environment, violating the isolation integral to maintaining coexisting virtual environments.

Answer (score 0):

1st try to update the pip with the below command and try again.

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: This is not a good idea for a Conda environment. This will result in clobbering the Conda-installed version of pip with the PyPI version.

Comment: I took your idea and installed the package via conda. Everything is working now!

Comment: i am glad it helped you. Please close your question by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer that helped you most :D