visual studio extensions with brew venv
I am on macbook, and using visual studio code for python development. I have not had this issue with my older macs with pipenv. I have installed some AWS extensions that I need to work with my python venv(on Brew python). sample extension is boto3
However the .py file in my venv on visual studio code does not detect boto3 extension.
How do I get the extension detected within venv on visual studio code?
Thanks in advance.

Maybe you want to know this? https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_working-with-python-interpreters

The article here mentions the extension installation would fail if source is PyPI using pipenv (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Boto3typed.boto3-ide).
Try using pip instead as suggested by the article: pip install boto3
Here is a reference link to a similar questions (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33388555/unable-to-install-boto3). Hope this helps.


This was usually caused by incorrect python interpreter. You could
use shortcuts "Cmd + Shift + P" and search for "Python: Select
Interpreter" to choose the correct python interpreter which you
installed the package in.
Ensure that you've install the boto3 package by command pip install boto3

